# The status of Mosaic Law during Jesus' lifetime

Tags: exegesis, textual-discrepancies, mosaic-law, words-of-jesus, matthew

How can the following verses be reconciled?

Matthew 5:18-20:

> “Amen, I say to you, until heaven and earth pass away, not the smallest letter or the smallest part of a letter will pass from the law, until all things have taken place. Therefore, whoever breaks one of the least of these commandments and teaches others to do so will be called least in the kingdom of heaven. But whoever obeys and teaches these commandments will be called greatest in the kingdom of heaven. I tell you, unless your righteousness surpasses that of the scribes and Pharisees, you will not enter into the kingdom of heaven.”

Matthew 23:1-3:

> ”Then Jesus spoke to the crowds and to his disciples,  saying, “The scribes and the Pharisees have taken their seat on the chair of Moses.  Therefore, do and observe all things whatsoever they tell you, but do not follow their example. For they preach but they do not practice”

Matthew 12:1-4:

> ”At that time Jesus was going through a field of grain on the sabbath. His disciples were hungry and began to pick the heads of grain and eat them.  When the Pharisees saw this, they said to him, “See, your disciples are doing what is unlawful to do on the sabbath.”  He said to them, “Have you not read what David did when he and his companions were hungry,  how he went into the house of God and ate the bread of offering, which neither he nor his companions but only the priests could lawfully eat?”

In chapter 5 Jesus is telling people to keep observing the Mosaic Law which obviously ended by the time he died and rose from the dead, and the same thing in chapter 23, but then in Matthew 12 before he died and rose he seems to be approving his disciples not observing it for no reason in particular.
I find it hard to accept that “these least commandments” in verse 19 don’t refer to the Mosaic law.  In fact the footnotes in the New American Bible agree with this.  Especially considering that the teachings preceding this are the Beatitudes and the teachings about keeping your salt and not hiding your light.  It is hard to see how these could be “least” commandments since they are so abstract, the much more intuitive interpretation is that they are aspects of the Mosaic law that people might not take seriously.  Also in verse 17 he speaks of the “law and prophets.”  The “therefore” in verse 19 shows that he is still talking about the law and the prophets, and then in verse 20 he talks about the scribes and the Pharisees, so I don’t see how “these least commandments” in verse 19 could refer to Jesus’ laws from the Sermon on the Mount given that it is right between unambiguous references to the Mosaic law.  This is corroborated by Matthew 23:1-4 where he tells people to follow the traditions of the elders as communicated by the Pharisees.  How can this be squared with the grain-picking controversy (Luke 6:1-5), the handwashing controversy (Mark 7), and when he says that all foods are clean (Mark 7:18-19)?  Wouldn’t people have been confused if they were aware of all of these things at the same time?

Comment: I don't see what needs to be 'reconciled' here. Could you please add some clarity an detail in explanation ?

Comment: @NigelJ  In chapter 5 he is telling people to keep observing the Mosaic Law which obviously ended by the time he died and rose from the dead, and the same thing in chapter 23, but then in Matthew 12 before he died and rose he seems to be approving his disciples not observing it for no reason in particular.

Comment: Reading Matthew 12 through verse 8 may help.

Comment: Jesus makes a remark about the durability of law. Then he makes a remark about the commandments that _he has just given_. Matthew 5:18-20. These are two different things. I think you are missing that feature.

Comment: NABRE note on Matt 5:19 [14] Probably these commandmentsmeans those of the Mosaic law. But this is an interim ethic "until heaven and earth pass away.". Also see various questions on all these verses like "did jesus break sabbath", least commandment etc on hermeneutics se.

Answer (score 2):

> Think not that I am come to destroy the law, or the prophets: I am not come to destroy, but to fulfil. For verily I say unto you, Till heaven and earth pass, one jot or one tittle shall in no wise pass from the law, till all be fulfilled. Whosoever therefore shall break one of these least commandments, and shall teach men so, he shall be called the least in the kingdom of heaven: but whosoever shall do and teach *them*, the same shall be called great in the kingdom of heaven. For I say unto you, That except your *righteousness* shall exceed the righteousness of the scribes and Pharisees, ye shall in no case enter into the kingdom of heaven.

[Matthew 5:17-20 KJV](https://biblehub.com/kjv/matthew/5.htm)

Jesus states the durability of law, that law shall not pass till heaven and earth pass and till all is fulfilled.

From other scriptures we know that this will happen when Christ returns and when there are new heavens and a new earth wherein all that was promised is fulfilled.

Then he comments on the situation where someone might break one of these least commandments. That is to say, the commandments that he has just outlined in the previous verses of his discourse upon the mount.

Such a person will not be excluded from the kingdom, but they will be regarded as the least.

But there will also be, in the kingdom, those who 'do and teach'.

Thus the one who broke the least of the commandments of Jesus and and did not teach them, remaining in the kingdom, will be instructed by those who 'do and teach' (again, 'them' is not in the original) : doing by example and teaching unto instruction.

What a kingdom this is !

But within that kingdom 'that' (the original does not contain the word 'righteousness') of the scribes and Pharisees must be exceeded. For 'that' of the scribes and Pharisees was hypocrisy. They did not 'do' but they rather demanded others to keep a law that could not save or heal or deliver.

They had no righteousness, only a position and a hypocritical posture.

It requires something more than 'that' to enter into the kingdom of heaven.

And there one will be instructed by those who - first - 'do' and then (and only then ) 'teach'.

This sets forth the 'status of the Mosaic Law' during the days when Christ was upon this earth.

---

The matter of David and the shewbread needs careful handling and requires a further question though I am sure it will already have been dealt with on SE-C or SE-BH.

Comment: I put my response in the original question since it was too long.

Comment: @wmasse Your edit noted but my answer remains the same.